# Validating JS Tests against a JSON Schema

Tags: javascript, json, testing, postman, jsonschema

I have an API which returns response in the format

```
[
{"id": 12345,
"value": "some_string",
"practice_id": "12344"},

{"id": 12346,
"value": "some_other_string",
"practice_id": "12345"},
]
```

I am testing that the response validates a specific JSON-Schema, and my schema test is

```
response.body.should.have.schema({
        type: 'array',
        required: ['id', 'value', 'practice_id'],
        properties: {
            id: {
                type: 'number',
            },
            value: {
                type: 'string',
            },
            practice_id: {
                type: 'string',
                minLength: 5,
            }            
        }
    });
```

The issue is that the test passes even if I change the type of id to `string` or change the value of practice_id to `number`, which is not correct.

What am I doing wrong here? I am using [Postman-BDD](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postman-bdd) to validate the responses.

Comment: string works with number and id, but number and id cant contain string. Try to set value to number and you should get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your schema should be more like this:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items":
  {
    "required":
    [
        "id",
        "value",
        "practice_id"
    ],
    "properties":
    {
        "id":
        {
            "type": "number"
        },
        "value":
        {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "practice_id":
        {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 5
        }
    }
  }
}
```

You are missing the "items" keywords to actually define the content of the array. And this schema also gives an error in JSONBuddy on validating some sample data:
[image]

Comment: Am I required to add "items" when the response is an array of objects? If I use schema for a json object response than it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, you need to use "items" for an array if you want to specify the valid array elements. Please keep also in mind, that a JSON schema describes an open data model by default. This means an empty JSON schema allows any content.

Comment: Noted. Thank You.